# Cómo traer solo un registro en SQL

Tags: sql-server

Buenas tardes querida comunidad, vengo con una consulta simple pero que me ha tenido bastante tiempo pegado haciéndola. Necesito traer solo 1 registro de un total donde el campo donde hago el filtro es similar en otras líneas de un tabla.

Tengo la consulta:

```
select rut_pagador,  max(convert(int, periodo_remuneraciones)), 
       cod_act_economica, folio
FROM operaciones.[dbo].[ACTUALIZACION_EMPLEADORES_ESTEBAN]
where rut_pagador in (93538000)
group by rut_pagador,cod_act_economica,folio, periodo_remuneraciones
order by periodo_remuneraciones desc
```

donde el resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo necesito que me muestre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor su ayuda.

Comment: Probaste con incluir "LIMIT" en la sentencia?

Comment: Si estas utilizando SqlServer usa select TOP 1

Comment: @FrancoSchillage limit en mysql.. top en sql server

Comment: Ahora que veo lo que queres traer, no tiene logica, y puede que con TOP 1 no siempre devuelva esa fila que vos queres, porque todas las filas cumplen la condicion del gruop by, asi que la db no puede asegurar ese registro... ademas d elo que mostraste que queres, explicas porque queres esa?

Comment: En efecto, no está claro el criterio de ordenamiento / selección. Por qué esa fila y no otra de las siete con el mismo valor de rut, período y actividad económica?

Comment: En resumen solo quiero que me traiga el periodo_remuneraciones máximo, que en este caso es 202006 @Alfabravo

Comment: Pero con ese período tienes 7 folios, cual de ellos es el que quieres?

Comment: Todos esos, si dejé uno como ejemplo, pero necesito que me muestre toda la información que respecte al período máximo. @PatricioMoracho

Comment: @EstebanLopez, tú último comentario lo agregaría como edición a la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho, ahora me resultó lo que quería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez la forma más sencilla sea una subconsulta para obtener el último período

```
select rut_pagador,  
       periodo_remuneraciones
       cod_act_economica, 
       folio
       FROM operaciones.dbo.ACTUALIZACION_EMPLEADORES_ESTEBAN
       where rut_pagador in (93538000)
             AND periodo_remuneraciones = (select MAX(periodo_remuneraciones)
                                                  FROM operaciones.dbo.ACTUALIZACION_EMPLEADORES_ESTEBAN
                                                  where rut_pagador in (93538000)
                                         )
```